# Add JS to all webform

Tags: javascript, webforms, 9

I have a Drupal 9 custom theme and would like to attach a JS file on the webform.

Adding JS file in `themename.libraries.yml` does not work.

```
webform:
  js:
    theme:
      js/webform.min.js: {}
```

**What is the right way to attach a JS file to the other module(webform)?**

Answer (score 2):

Adding lines to `themename.libraries.yml` is not enough to add the JS, you just declared a library doing this.

Now if you want to use that library on all your theme pages, you need to add in `themename.info.yml`

```
libraries:
  - themename/webform
```

But if you just need to attach the library to your forms, you can use  the [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/9.0.x), target your webform ids and write
`$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'themename/webform';`

Comment: Is the `hook_form_alter` for a specific form id? I want to load a JS file on all webforms.

Comment: If this is the only solution I got, then I will add a JS if the form ID contains `webform_submission`. I can write something like this `if ( strpos($form['#form_id'], 'webform_submission') !== false ) { $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'myTheme/webform'; }`